# Convert Date type to Character type error in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I have a `datetime` type column in a table employees where I have some rows containing the value `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`. I would like to replace this value with 0 from my select query.

```
select 
    EmployeeNumber, 
    case when CONVERT(CHAR(10), [HireDate], 104) = '01.01.1900' 
           then 0 
           else [HireDate] 
    end  col
from 
    emp..Employees
```

But result still return the datetime type result `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

How can I get 0 instead of this value?

Could you please suggest?

Thanks
MZR

Comment: Already tried doesn't work

Comment: Make sure `CONVERT(CHAR(10), [HireDate],104)='01.01.1900'` but putting `CONVERT(CHAR(10), [HireDate],104)` in your `SELECT`

Comment: `0` is not a valid date time and you can't mix return types in the same case expression. In these cases SQL Server will use [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) to determine the leading type from all branches, and implicitly convert all results to this time. Since `DATETIME` has a higher precedence than `INT`, 0 is implicitly converted to a datetime. If you want to control this you will need to use explicit conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 is the default value for [datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

You could either change that 0 to NULL:

```
    CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), [HireDate], 104) = '01.01.1900' THEN NULL
        ELSE [HireDate]
    END AS HireDate
```

OR, if you really want it to be 0, you should cast your datetime column to something else:

```
    CASE 
        WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), [HireDate], 104) = '01.01.1900' THEN '0'
        ELSE CAST([HireDate] AS varchar(50))
    END AS HireDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks George,
Got the solution.
We need to change the resulting column type as well, otherwise automatic conversion will happen.

```
select EmployeeNumber, case when CONVERT(CHAR(10),
   [HireDate],104)='01.01.1900' then '0'  else CAST(HireDate AS 
   varchar(50)) end  col
   from rr..Employees
```

BR
MZR

Comment: There is no need to post your own solution if it is the same as one already posted. Simply just mark the answer that helped as [the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), which will indicate to others that it helped, and also discourage others from wasting time by providing new answers since your problem has been solved.